# Android Studio, Is there an easier way to format large blocks of text?

Tags: java, android, xml, text, formatting

I am relatively new to coding, great community here at StackOverflow, love it tremendously. Got a lot of my questions answered already, except Im still finding it difficult to format large batches of text in android studio and Im looking for answers/suggestions/workarounds. Thanks in advance.

PROBLEM: 
On Android Studio 1.3, Im developing an app that allows the user to quickly access large amounts of text information on the screen. I would like to make the code a little more efficient and manageable. The text contains bullets, superscripts, subscripts... making it impossible to edit everything in strings.xml (couldnt get super/subscripts formatting in strings.xml). 

I currently have everything in the activity.java files, with formatting being managed with Html.fromHtml(); (It was the only way i could get the super/subscripts to work). This is proving inconvenient as there are many activities, each with loads of text and would love it if there was a way to have everything centralized in strings.xml, if possible. 
If not, are there any recommendations on how to deal with pages of text (other than importing a picture of the text already properly formatted)? Is there a list of available text formatting tags or code I can use in xml and java for simple things like bullets, indentations, and superscripts?

EXAMPLE:
This is an example of the text I am working with, more or less the format I wish to have across the various activities:

```
Given sufficient time/ resources, you may consider ordering Urine Cl-.

 If UCl is less than 10, consider: 

    • Vomiting.

    • Diuretics.

 
 If UCl greater than 10, check for hypertension:

 - If hypertensive, consider: 

    • Exogenous Steroids.

    • Cushing Syndrome. 

    • Primary Hyperaldosteronism.

    • Liddle Syndrome.

 
- If normotensive, consider:

    • Surreptitous Diuretics.

    • Bartter Syndrome.

    • Gitlemann Syndrome.
```

and this is the code from the activity.java:

```
mTextMetAlComp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_simmetalk3);
mTextMetAlComp.setText(Html.fromHtml("Given sufficient time/ resources, you    may consider ordering Urine Cl<sup><small>-</small></sup>.\n" +
            "    <br> <blockquote>If U<sub><small>Cl</small></sub> < 10, consider:" +
            "    <br>    • Vomiting. " +
            "    <br>    • Diuretics.</blockquote>" +
            "    <br> <blockquote>If U<sub><small>Cl</small></sub> > 10, check for hypertension:\n" +
            "    <br> <u>- If hypertensive, consider:</u> " +
            "    <br>    • Exogenous Steroids. " +
            "    <br>    • Cushing Syndrome.\n" +
            "    <br>    • Primary Hyperaldosteronism. " +
            "    <br>    • Liddle Syndrome." +
            "    <br> <br> <u>- If normotensive, consider:</u>\n" +
            "    <br>    • Surreptitous Diuretics. " +
            "    <br>    • Bartter Syndrome. " +
            "    <br>    • Gitlemann Syndrome.</blockquote>"));
```

Any advice is appreciated

Comment: "are there any recommendations on how to deal with pages of text (other than importing a picture of the text already properly formatted)?" -- put the HTML in HTML files in `assets/` or `res/raw/`. I'm not quite certain why you are using `TextView` here instead of `WebView`; if you switch to `WebView`, it can load from assets directly. With regards to what is supported by `Html.fromHtml()`, refer to [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/text/Html.java) (particularly `handleStartTag()`).

Comment: Use Webview and show your HTML file there...

Comment: @CommonsWare I didnt think WebView was for text, i had assumed it was for importing webpages or something to do with having an internet connection, so I didnt look into it for this project. It is better than having to deal with textView, Thank you both for that advice. I dont have any assets/ or raw/ folders though, so I I have just been using HTML directly in the activity.java file.

Comment: "so I I have just been using HTML directly in the activity.java file" -- that is not a particularly good choice for static HTML. The Web, for example, is dominated by static HTML, and most static HTML comes in the form of plain text files containing HTML markup. While some Web pages are dynamically generated (client-side or server-side) using programming languages and concatenation, the objective is usually to have larger pieces of that be plain files, so they can be edited more easily.